# Emmet on atom not working properly

Tags: html, atom-editor, emmet

Hi I'm using **Emmet** on **Atom** code editor and it works fine only with the simple tags like `meta`.

Nevertheless when I try something complex like `ul>li*5` or  `meta[property=""]` and then press tab, nothing happens.

**Anyone know how to fix this?**

Comment: Might want to try here: https://github.com/emmetio/emmet-atom/issues

Comment: it seem that if i use ctrl+e instead of tab it works with the complex instructions.I don't know why. Thanks for help

Comment: I got same problem - [refer here](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet-atom/issues/108)

Answer (score 5):

It happened to me as well, the problem is that the same hotkey(tab) is set to multiple actions, so my solution was to edit the expand action like this.

go to Settings > Packages > Search Emmet...
on the keybindings get the last one tab and click on the copy icon

[]<-  (something like that)

then go to Edit > Keymap... and copy the next there

```
'atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
  'ctrl-alt-shift-c': 'emmet:expand-abbreviation'
```

As the keymap.. overrides all the other keybindings this one will work over all other definitions.

*Note: if you use 'tab' as key binding it will only be used for expand-emmet, so you won't be able to actually tab__(2spaces) in HTML, PHP, more... files*

**HOPE IT HELPS**

Comment: As there are lot of shortcuts to remember. Either its better to use combination `ctrl-alt-e` instead of `ctrl-e`

Answer (score 3):

you find after installing emmet, tab completion doesn’t work as described in the documentation, go to Atom > Keymap or File > Keymap add the following code, then restart Atom (this fix worked for me):

```
'atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
'tab': 'emmet:expand-abbreviation-with-tab'
```

Answer is from

https://github.com/emmetio/emmet-atom/issues/503

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me.

You go to Atom > Keymap or File > Keymap add the following code, then restart Atom.

```
 'atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
  'tab': 'emmet:expand-abbreviation-with-tab'
```

[image: Atom Emmet Tab Button Remapped]

Answer (score 0):

Just want to mention that like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65645633/7773582 I had to restart Atom installed in Ubuntu Linux Groovy Gorilla to get my own keymap.cson for a new Keybinding with

```
'atom-text-editor[data-grammar="text html basic"]:not([mini]),
atom-text-editor[data-grammar~="erb"]:not([mini]),
atom-text-editor[data-grammar~="jade"]:not([mini]),
atom-text-editor[data-grammar~="css"]:not([mini]),
atom-text-editor[data-grammar~="stylus"]:not([mini]),
atom-text-editor[data-grammar~="sass"]:not([mini]),
atom-text-editor[data-grammar~="scss"]:not([mini])':
  'shift-enter': 'emmet:expand-abbreviation-with-tab'
```

for the Emmet-Plugin to unfold its Syntax to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Any add-ons you install will most likely wont work if you dont restart your app.

If all solutions mentioned here does not take any effect to your Atom app is simply because your Atom app is STILL working in the backgroud even if you closed it.
Simple solution is go to Task Manager and End Task your Atom app there...

Hope it helps...
Happy Learning...