# Atom -- snippets not working

Tags: atom-editor

The following are two of the snippets I have scripted in snippets.cson file:

```
'.source.python':
  'print statement':
    'prefix': 'pr'
    'body' : 'print "${1:Hello world}"'


'.source.python':
  'Argument variables import':
    'prefix' : 'argv'
    'body' : 'from sys import argv'
```

The first one doesn't work, but the second one does. Help please.

Ps.

The snippets file was BLANK when I first installed atom on my machine. I use Ubuntu 16.04. Is that normal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the root of your problem is that your scope `.source.python` was declared twice.

To answer your second question first, No, my snippets.cson file was not blank when I first opened it. Instead, it contained the following:

```
# Your snippets
#
# Atom snippets allow you to enter a simple prefix in the editor and hit tab to
# expand the prefix into a larger code block with templated values.
#
# You can create a new snippet in this file by typing "snip" and then hitting
# tab.
#
# An example CoffeeScript snippet to expand log to console.log:
#
# '.source.coffee':
#   'Console log':
#     'prefix': 'log'
#     'body': 'console.log $1'
#
# Each scope (e.g. '.source.coffee' above) can only be declared once.
#
# This file uses CoffeeScript Object Notation (CSON).
# If you are unfamiliar with CSON, you can read more about it in the
# Atom Flight Manual:
# http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#_cson
```

(This is on MacOS, though).

Notice how it instructs you that each scope can only be declared once. I think if you modify your two snippets to be included in the same scope, they will work as expected.

Changing your `snippets.cson` to the following appears to work for me:

```
'.source.python':
  'print statement':
    'prefix': 'pr'
    'body' : 'print "${1:Hello world}"'

  'Argument variables import':
    'prefix' : 'argv'
    'body' : 'from sys import argv'
```

I can access both snippets from the snippets import menu once I make the `.source.python` scope unique.

Comment: I have installed atom on windows 10 before and I remember having read something like this. On Ubuntu however, literally blank.\

Comment: Which declaration takes precedence? One before or after?

Comment: I suspect the one _after_, since it's appears to be a declarative language. Also, the OP suggested that his second snippet was working, but not the first.

Comment: @NageshEranki That's interesting. I suspect that this is a bug with Ubuntu, and should probably be filed with the Atom project. I wouldn't suspect this to be something that's platform-dependent, though.

Comment: @NageshEranki Feel free to accept the answer if it worked for you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Atom 1.53.0 x64 on Ubuntu 20.10 ("groovy gorilla"):

I had to disable the "build-in" snippets in "Settings" in the Core-Package "language-html" (0.53.1). From there I copied the snippet for a prefix, pasted it into my own local snippets.cson and changed it to my needs.

I also had to restart Atom to get the editor to show my custom snippet for usage.

The original snippets.cson was blank in my case, too. No hints, no example.
Pure `vi`-feeling :-)