# Atom won't Autocomplete HTML tag with NextJS using language-babel

Tags: next.js, atom-editor

I am using Atom with language-babel but it won't autocomplete html tags in .js files.

I am not sure what is missing because the autocomplete is working on .html files.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using atom-react and emmet, then added this code to the keymap.cson file ( Atom > Keymap or File > Keymap )

```
'atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
  'tab': 'emmet:expand-abbreviation-with-tab'
```

Reference:

[Emmet on atom not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36610293/emmet-on-atom-not-working-properly)